# Peskin and Schroeder Pg. 228: Expanding resummed propagator around the physical pole

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, singularities, propagator

I am having difficulty wrapping my head around this particular statement and equation (7.44) on pg. 228 of P&S,

[image]

I think I understand that "~" sign here is trying to denote at under $p^0 \to E_\vec{p}$ both LHS and RHS have the same pole structure (although I must admit that I fail to see it unless $m_0^2 - M^2 = m^2$ which seems incorrect knowing that later we define $m^2=m_0^2 Z-\delta m$. How does one go around the expansion he is talking about and possibly get the RHS upto "~" with the (regular) terms? I feel I am missing either some small piece/trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I posted the question, I have been trying to work out the details and I think I have got it narrowed down to this :

Using the Kallan-Lehmann spectral representation, we can say that we want our new propagator (the LHS) which includes the 1PI contributions to be "~" to the RHS  (which is the Kallan-Lehmann representation).

We want to have matching poles and residues at $p^2 \to m^2$ :

$$ \frac{i}{p^2-m_0^2-M^2(p^2)} = \frac{i Z}{p^2-m^2} +\int \frac{dq^2}{2\pi} \rho(q^2) \frac{i}{p^2-q^2}  $$

where the second term has no poles at $p^2 \to m^2$ giving us the +(regular) part.

So, we want to match the poles on LHS and the first term in the RHS on in the above expression,
$$ p^2-m_0^2-M^2(p^2)=0 \quad \text{when} \; p^2=m^2 $$
$$ \implies m^2=m_0^2+M^2(m^2) $$

We also want to match the residues to understand what $Z$ is for our case. Rearranging the above equation, when we match residues we must have,
$$\frac{p^2-m^2}{p^2-m_0^2-M^2 \left(p^2\right)} \longrightarrow Z \quad \text { as } \quad p^2 \rightarrow m^2$$

To get an expression for $Z$ we can Taylor expand $M^2(p^2)$ around $p^2=m^2$,
$$ M^2(p^2)\approx M^2(m^2)+ (p^2-m^2)\frac{dM^2(p^2)}{dp^2}\Big\vert_{p^2=m^2} + \text{Higher order terms} $$
Plugging this into the expression above,
\begin{gathered}
\frac{p^2-m_0^2-\left\{ M^2(m^2)-(p^2-m^2)\frac{dM^2(p^2)}{dp^2}\Big\vert_{p^2=m^2}\right\}}{p^2-m^2} \longrightarrow Z^{-1} \\
\frac{p^2-m_0^2- M^2(m^2)+(p^2-m^2)\frac{dM^2(p^2)}{dp^2}\Big\vert_{p^2=m^2}}{p^2-m^2} \longrightarrow Z^{-1}\\
\frac{p^2-m^2+(p^2-m^2)\frac{dM^2(p^2)}{dp^2}\Big\vert_{p^2=m^2}}{p^2-m^2} \longrightarrow Z^{-1}\\
\Rightarrow 1-\frac{dM^2(p^2)}{dp^2}\Big\vert_{p^2=m^2} \stackrel{}{=} Z^{-1}
\end{gathered}

So, for the $m$ and $Z$ that we derived, the above expression should be justified.